# How to set the filepath to the most recent folder in python?

Tags: python, export

I want to call the fbx exporter using

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

which works fine but it doesn't default to the most recent folder location. I know that I can change this by setting it's filepath to something else

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx('INVOKE_DEFAULT', filepath=bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath))
```

but how do I change this code so it is set to the most recent file?